# Oracle APEX format a cell based on users input

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex

I am currently assisting in creating an Oracle APEX application and my task has been to be able to 'make' the cells in a table automatically update the cells background based on the users imput.
For example:
If the user enters AL (Annual Leave) then this will format the background to Yello
If the user enters X it will format the cell background to grey.
If the user enters C (Training Course) it will format it to 'peach'

I have already looked around on here and found a few guides but none are for specifically this, which is why I decided to ask a new question.

Sample of the table that I would like to format:
[image: Example]

I have been told that this can be done in javascript, which I have some knowledge in.
I was wondering if this can be done in CSS?
Since HTML wouldn't be possible.

Comment: So it is a classic report but not tabular form? (Judging from the screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the region a static ID. 
Put these style rules somewhere, for example page heading:

```
<style>
.annual{
background-color:yellow;
}
.ex{
background-color:grey;
}
.trainingcourse{
background-color:peach;
}
</style>
```

Run this javascript but replace the STATICID with the static id of your report. Add cases and classes where required. The advantage here is that you steer the look from your CSS and not by using jquery. You could assign a backgroundcolor straight away if you do prefer that, but my own preference is to keep this separated.

```
$("#report_STATICID td[headers]").each(function(){
   var lTest = $(this).text(), lClass;
   switch(lTest){
      case 'AL':
         lClass = "annual";
         break;
      case 'X':
         lClass = "ex";
         break;
      case 'C':
         lClass = "trainingcourse";
         break;
   };
   if(lClass){
      $(this).addClass(lClass);
   };
})
```

---

Edit: As may be evident from the comments, the theme you are using and thus the template for your region is very important in these matters.
(note: in the samples below I'm using a simple classic report based on a select on the emp table with static id empreport)
In this case @Robovisits is using Theme 13 - Classic Blue. The first thing to check is markup:
[image: screenshot of html snippet concerning report in theme 13]
This allows you to identify whether the selectors are correct and will target the correct elements. The best way to verify this is by running the selectors from the console in the browser's developer tools and inspect the return values.
Now when I run this code:

```
$("#report_empreport td[headers]").each(function(){
   var lTest = $(this).text(), lClass;
   switch(lTest){
      case 'KING':
         lClass = "class1";
         break;
      case 'PICARD':
         lClass = "class2";
         break;
      case 'FRANCINE':
         lClass = "class3";
         break;
   };
   if(lClass){
      $(this).addClass(lClass);
   };
})
```

I then rightclick a column I believe should be affected by this and choose to inspect the element (in this case I'm in the dev tools of Chrome).
[image: affected element in html pane]
Good, so my cell with KING in it indeed received the correct class. Now why doesn't it get colored?
Since I want to color using CSS I need to select the affected element in the html pane, and then I can check in the CSS pane to the right:
[image: css pane overview before override]
As you can see, the CSS for class1 is being overridden! What happens here is that another rule with more specificity has precedence over our rule. Bluntly put, the more specific a selector is, the more weight it has in precedence for applying a rule. 
This can be fixed by giving the selector I'm using more "weight".

```
body table.t13Standard td.class1{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

[image: css pane after override]

Note: there is also the option to use !important to simply override anything, no matter the specificity. I generally avoid that unless it actually makes sense. It could look like this:

```
.class1{
background-color:yellow !important;
}
```

[image: colours!]

Comment: Could you expand a bit? For instance, do you get any javascript error by chance? Did you instead the html for one of the should-be-affected cells and did you see the correct class added there? (indicates css is not being overridden correctly) Did you give the report a static id? (It might be a theme-related issue)

Comment: I have a feeling that it may be with the Theme, as I got no errors adding it, but nothing changed. I am currently using the Classic Blue theme

Comment: I can only recommend that you take a quick inspection of the html. When the javascript has run (on load or after refresh i presume) inspect one of the cells that should have been affected, for example one with AL in it. Does the cell have the class added to it? If it does, then it probably has to do with css overrides. This you can also check with the proper tools (eg firebug in firefox, developer tools in chrome, check the styles tag and see if the style has an override). I wish it was more clearcut, but going with css and javascript requires these things to check how and if they work.

Comment: On the report that I am using, I have given it a Static ID:
http://robovisits.com/images/CSS%20and%20StaticID.PNG

And the Javascript:
http://robovisits.com/images/JS1.PNG & 
http://robovisits.com/images/js2.PNG

Apologies for the belated reply too, I've been on AL myself :-) @Tom

Comment: Looks okay but it may still be the theme does something else with the output, causing the dynamic action not to play ball. If possible, can you get a screenshot of the output html code concerning the report region? Another important bit: what browser is this meant for?

Comment: The reports are using SQL queries: http://robovisits.com/images/Report.PNG
Also it is meant to be used accross browsers (firefox, chrome, opera, IE) @Tom

Comment: Ah - I didn't mean region source, I meant the html code you get when the page is run (either from a dev tools pane or rightclick-view source- - if you know where/what to look for of course. I'd play with the theme and see what it produces but currently can't.

Comment: I can't publicize that as it has company information on, is there anyway I can email it to you? @Tom

Comment: Hey Robo, I've been naughty and took some time to look at this on apex.oracle.com with an own example. I think you may have a problem with CSS overriding, and I've detailed this in an edit of my anwser! See if that solves your issue.

Comment: apologies for being a pest! but my column headers as all COL01, COL02 etc... up until COL33
http://robovisits.com/images/CSS.PNG

Comment: Under this section "This allows you to identify whether the selectors are correct and will target the correct elements. The best way to verify this is by running the selectors from the console in the browser's developer tools and inspect the return values.
Now when I run this code:" it is not modifying the classes, but keeping them all the same as they were "t13dataalt" @Tom

Comment: I see that your static id is "#TestReport#" for some reason. Do the hashtags need to be there? Using that in a jQuery selector might throw it mightily off as the hashsign is used to indicate a selector by id. In your case this would make the selector `#report_#TestReport#` - that looks really weird! I'd remove those hashes from the static id.

Comment: Wh...What is happening!? Strange! You're right though. Damn - the ID is set to `TestReport` on the region level. However, when you look ath the `CSS.PNG` image you posted earlier you can see that the report container has `report_#TestReport#`! You need to 1) go to report attributes and take note of the REPORT template (not region!)  and 2) go to templates and inspect that report template. In "Before Rows" you can see the static id construction: `id="report_#REGION_STATIC_ID#"`. I'm hoping it is a custom template problem... What is stupid of me to ask so late: what apex version are you on?

Comment: I've modified the report template now and changed report_#TestReport# to report_TestReport also I am using Application Express 4.2.2.00.11 @Tom

Comment: I deleted my previous comment since it held my email. We're taking this further up through mail because I'm not able to move this to chat due to Robo's insufficient rep. I'll update my answer as we find more.